# Can not able to customise Pin(Marker) and it's info window in Mapbox, MapboxGL.MapView in React Natvie

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

We are developing application in React Native, our requirement is on map need to show Multiple Marker. and when user press on it should show info window with that particular location image on circle shape and arrow that indicate with marker you can see on attached images. This issue is almost in android but in ios customise is working fine.

We have used below version of Mapbox and React native

```
Run on Platform OS: [Android 10]
@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps Version [8.4.0]
React Native Version [0.66.1]
```

We have tried all possible way to implement but each component have something issue.
Like
We have tried below compoments
MapboxGL.PointAnnotation without any sub Result:- view pin will visible but when press on it app get crash in android

MapboxGL.ShapeSource Result:- Nothing display

MapboxGL.PointAnnotation with Image view Result:- Display Pin but only work local image

MapboxGL.MarkerView Result:- Not stable, on zoom/move map marker gove any where

Here is my code

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Platform, ScrollView, TextInput } from "react-native";
import { Size } from "../../utils/sizes";
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
import styles from "./styles";
import Colors from "../../utils/Colors";
import Strings from "../../utils/Strings";
import Toggle from "../../components/Toggle";
import { Assets } from "../../assets/icons";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import { ACCESSTOKEN } from "../../utils/Constants";
MapboxGL.setAccessToken(ACCESSTOKEN);
const MapBod_Height = Size.height * 0.5;

export default function AddPost(props) {

    const [ImageGallery, setImageGallery] = useState(null)
    const [region, setRegion] = useState({
        latitude: 23.0225,
        longitude: 72.5714,
        screenPointX: 100,
        screenPointY: 100,
    })

    //Skipping first iteration (exactly like componentWillReceiveProps):
    const isFirstRun = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFirstRun.current) {
            isFirstRun.current = false;
            onClickGallery()
            // requestCameraPermission()
        } else {
        }
    }, [CommonReducer])

    const onClickGallery = () => {
        var options = {
            mediaType: 'photo',
            maxWidth: 800,
            maxHeight: 800
        };
        launchImageLibrary(options,
            (response) => {
                console.log(response, 'get image response')
                if (response.didCancel) { setCancelText("We couldn't access your device's gallery") }
                else if (response.errorCode) { setCancelText("We couldn't access your device's gallery") }
                else {
                    setImageGallery(response)
                }
            })
    }

    const onPress = (event) => {
        const { geometry, properties } = event;
        setRegion({
            latitude: geometry.coordinates[1],
            longitude: geometry.coordinates[0],
            screenPointX: properties.screenPointX,
            screenPointY: properties.screenPointY,
        });
    }

    const ImageMarker = ({ children }) =>
        Platform.select({
            ios: children,
            android: <Text
                style={{
                    lineHeight: 60,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                }}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        });


    return (
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            enableResetScrollToCoords={false}
        >
            {ImageGallery && <View style={styles.container}>

                <MapboxGL.MapView
                    style={{ height: MapBod_Height }}
                    styleURL={"mapbox://styles/ailebo/ckvhrplb02gjs14lzqfao134z"}
                    onPress={onPress}>
                    <MapboxGL.UserLocation />
                    <MapboxGL.Camera
                        zoomLevel={8}
                        animationMode={'flyTo'}
                        animationDuration={1100}
                        centerCoordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                    />

                    {/* Result:- Can load only local assets, and can not customze marker */}
                    {/* <MapboxGL.Annotation
                        id={'-annotation'}
                        key={"123"}
                        onPress={(event) => console.log("event ==> ", event)}
                        icon={Assets.bike}
                        coordinates={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                    /> */}


                    {/* Result:- Red pin, on click of that app get crash */}
                    {/* <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation coordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]} /> */}


                    {/* Result:- Nothing display */}
                    {/* <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
                        id='allMarkers'
                        shape={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                    >
                        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                            id='markersLevel2'
                            style={{
                                iconImage: 'https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_525159.png', //'https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_525160.png'
                                iconSize: 0.05,
                            }}
                        />
                        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                            id='markersLevel1'
                            style={{
                                iconImage: ['get', 'markerImage'],
                                iconSize: 0.09,
                            }}
                        />
                    </MapboxGL.ShapeSource> */}

                    {/* Result:- Nothing display */}
                    {/* <MapboxGL.Images
                        images={Assets.tree}
                        onImageMissing={url =>
                            console.log("url ", url)
                        }
                    /> */}

                    {/* Result:- Display Pin but only work local image */}
                    {/* <View>
                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                            id={'-annotation'}
                            key={"123"}
                            coordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                            title={"title"}>
                            <ImageMarker>
                                <Image
                                    source={Assets.tree}
                                    style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                                />
                            </ImageMarker>
                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                    </View> */}


                    {/* Result:- Nothing display */}
                    {/* <View>
                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                            id={'-annotation'}
                            key={"123"}
                            coordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                            title={"title"}>
                            <MapboxGL.Callout title='your-title' />
                            <View style={{ height: 80, width: 80, }}>
                                <Text style={styles.annotationFill}>
                                    {<Image source={{ uri: 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/abott@adorable.io.png' }} style={{ height: 80, width: 40, }} />}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                    </View> */}


                    {/* Result:- Black Pin and on click of that app get crash */}
                    {/* <View>
                        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                            id={'-annotation'}
                            key={"123"}
                            coordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}
                            title={"title"}>
                            <View style={{ height: 80, width: 40, backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <View style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#000000', borderRadius: 40 / 2 }}>
                                    <Image
                                        style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }}
                                        source={Assets.tree}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ width: 2, height: 20, backgroundColor: '#000000' }} />
                            </View>
                        </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
                    </View> */}

                    {/* Result:- Not stable, on zoom/move map marker gose any where */}
                    {/* <MapboxGL.MarkerView id={"marker"} coordinate={[region.longitude, region.latitude]}>
                        <View>
                            <View style={styles.markerContainer}>
                                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                                    <Image source={{ uri: ImageGallery.uri }} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: "red", resizeMode: "cover", }} />
                                </View>
                                <Image source={Assets.back_icon} style={{ width: 10, height: 10, }} />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </MapboxGL.MarkerView> */}

                </MapboxGL.MapView>
            </View>
            }
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
}
```

I have attached images what i want.

[image]

[image]

[image]